# I have a visual studio code terminal problem how do i fix it so that i have the integrated one instead of external?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm using **VS Code** on *Windows 10*. I had no problems until a few hours ago (at the time of post), whenever I want to **run** a python program, it opens terminals **outside** of VS Code like **Win32** and **Git Bash**. How do I change it back to the ***integrated terminal*** I usually had?

Comment: Try `F1` and `Developer: Reload Window`. **Ctrl+Shif+\`** to open a new intergrated terminal. If this doesn't work, close and reopen your VS Code. If still not work, have you tried right click the codes `Run Python File in Terminal`? Is your default terminal powershell (Could you please provide a sreen shot of your VS Code window)?

Answer (score 1):

With your Python file open in VS Code:

1. Go to Run > Open Configurations, if you get prompted select "Python File"
2. In the launch.json file, change the value of "console" to "integratedTerminal"